# Ho wto pass values using notification?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have 2 view controllers-1 for entering the value from the user and another to display value in a table view. The coding goes as follows:

This is for displaying the value passed by the notification:

ListTableViewContrller.m

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *namearray;
@end

@implementation ListTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(receieveTestNotificatiom:) name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)receieveTestNotificatiom:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    _namearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"USERNAME"], nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _namearray.count;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellreuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[_namearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This is for entering the data from the user in a view controller named as `source.m`-

```
- (IBAction)senddata:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_nametextfield.text forKey:@"USERNAME"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:dict];
}
```

When i try to run my application, it is not displaying the entered value in the table view controller. Why is it so? Thanks in advance......

Comment: what teh result u get in Namearray

Comment: i get the values that are entered in the text field.

Comment: can you show /print your name array, your coding is fine but it missed the index

Comment: shoe sir please rectify my coding with yours. at which part am i making the mistake u can just retype the code & give me. thanks

Comment: can you print this **notification.userInfo** and print **_namearray**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir I tried to print the values and it displayed the values that i was entering in the text field. but it is not showing in the table view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like and try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// allocate the memory here
_namearray=[NSMutableArray new];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(receieveTestNotificatiom:) name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];


}

-(void)receieveTestNotificatiom:(NSNotification *)notification
{



  NSString *value = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@",[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"USERNAME"]];

  NSLog(@"%@ value", [notification userInfo]);
  [_namearray addobject:value];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: show me what the result u get here  NSLog(@"%@ value", [notification userInfo]);

Comment: the o/p comes the text that i have entered in the text field... but it is not displaying in the table

Comment: yes sir it is working but whenever i enter the second name it erases the first one in the table. why is it so?

Comment: ok you need the all values correct, I removed this line  **[_namearray removeallobjects];** , now your array has hold the value, try once and let me know , if working fine give the vpvote else we continue further discussion

Answer (score 0):

your code looks ok. but do you really want to reinstantiate the array every time you receive a notification? or do you want to instantiate the array only once and then **add** values you get via notification? if the last is what you want here is my solution:

**receiving tableviewcontroller**

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *names;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedNotification:) name:@"NEW_NAME_NOTIFICATION" object:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return self.names.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NameCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}

- (void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [self.names addObject:notification.userInfo[@"value"]];
  [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.names.count - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)names {
  if (!_names) {
    _names = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  return _names;
}

@end
```

**viewcontroller that posts notifications**

```
@interface NewNameViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation NewNameViewController

- (IBAction)doneBarButtonItemTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
  [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NEW_NAME_NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:@{@"value": self.textField.text}];
  }];
}

@end
```

Comment: sir u didnt say me where is the problem in my coding?

Comment: i said "your code looks ok". i can't see anything wrong. maybe the problem is some other part of your code that you did not post?! do you want to share some more so i can help?